# Angular 7 new Code for routing.. Old Angular Routing Code not working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular and I am trying to fix some code that I got from a blog here for Applications Insights integration:- https://geeklearning.io/monitor-your-angular-app-with-application-insights/

Can someone with Angular 7 help me fix that Routing code marked below in the code section what I can use there? I am completely new to Angular and would need all the help.

Apprecaite it, Thank you!

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ResolveEnd, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import { AppInsights } from 'applicationinsights-js';
import { NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class MonitoringService {

    private routerSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        if (environment.appInsights && environment.appInsights.instrumentationKey) {
            AppInsights.downloadAndSetup(environment.appInsights);
        }

/* THIS IS THE CODE NOT WORKING AS ITS OLD ANGULAR and I AM USING ANGULAR 7 */
        this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
            .filter(event => event instanceof ResolveEnd)
            .subscribe((event: ResolveEnd) => {
                const activatedComponent = this.getActivatedComponent(event.state.root);
                if (activatedComponent) {
                    this.logPageView(`${activatedComponent.name} ${this.getRouteTemplate(event.state.root)}`, event.urlAfterRedirects);
                }
            }); 

/* End of the Angular code not working */

    }

    setAuthenticatedUserId(userId: string): void {
        AppInsights.setAuthenticatedUserContext(userId);
    }

    private getActivatedComponent(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): any {

        if (snapshot.firstChild) {
            return this.getActivatedComponent(snapshot.firstChild);
        }

        return snapshot.component;
    }

    private getRouteTemplate(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
        let path = '';
        if (snapshot.routeConfig) {
            path += snapshot.routeConfig.path;
        }

        if (snapshot.firstChild) {
            return path + this.getRouteTemplate(snapshot.firstChild);
        }

        return path;
    }
```

Comment: Would be good to know what the code actually should do

Answer (score 0):

Did some research on stackoverflow and got the following code as replacement for the old code and now its working:-

```
/* OLD CODE BELOW which didnt work for Angular 7 */
      /*this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
                .filter(event => event instanceof ResolveEnd)
                .subscribe((event: ResolveEnd) => {
                    const activatedComponent = this.getActivatedComponent(event.state.root);
                    if (activatedComponent) {
                        this.logPageView(`${activatedComponent.name} ${this.getRouteTemplate(event.state.root)}`, event.urlAfterRedirects);
                    }
                }); */

    /* Following is the replacement new code (in Angular 7) I used for above code and it works */
                router.events.pipe(
                    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)  
                  ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
                    const activatedComponent = this.getActivatedComponent(router.routerState.snapshot.root);
                    if (activatedComponent) {
                        this.logPageView(`${activatedComponent.name} ${this.getRouteTemplate(router.routerState.snapshot.root)}`, event.urlAfterRedirects);
                    }
                  });
```